# RHEL 8 - OpenSSH - Use separate groups and ports to manage connections for SSH and sftp

Tags: ssh, rhel, openssh, sftp

All,
I realize there are various posts out there that discuss how to configure different ports for ssh and sftp. What I cannot find much info is how to then manage these function with separate "security" groups. The catch here is that my intent is that these groups have no effect on each other, in that membership in one does not necessarily allow or deny membership to the other. Plane and simple, if you are in the `sshuser` group you are granted access to ssh on `port 22`. If you are in the `sftpuser` group you are granted access to the sftp capability on `port 2100`. Membership in both groups would allow access to ssh on 22 and sftp on 2100.

I have included the below info for context :

**sshd_config (relevant pats only)**

```
Port 22
Port 2100

AllowGroups sshUsers sftpUsers

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -d /files

Match Group sftpUsers LocalPort 2100
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/%u
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This configuration was built following various posts. Please assume the appropriate groups exist and directory permissions created for the ChrootDirectory. The above does not allow me to ssh or sftp as it appears things conflict.

Thanks

Comment: If someone has ssh access is it actually possible to deny sftp through that ssh service?

Comment: Post the /var/log/secure logs and /var/log/messages

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate SSH services with a dedicated sshd_config file each - one listening on port 22, the other on port 2100.

Comment: How could this be implemented?